# Pymongo update_one to have an 'undefined' field

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Wanted to know if it was possible to update a field in mongo to `undefined` using `pymongo`?

I know it's possible within Mongo `"myField": undefined`...but can't find anything specifically showing how to update to `undefined` with pymongo.

Basically just want to do the following:

`mongo.update_one(filter={"_id": UUID('foo')}, update={"$set": {"myField": undefined}})`

This is for testing where I need to test an API retrieving an undefined field.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the table here](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/index.html) there is no Python value that is converted to `undefined`.

The `undefined` type only exists natively in JS, you should use `null` / `None` instead.

Comment: Yea...that's what I saw....was just checking if anyone happened to know of anything.

Answer (score 0):

pyMongo is less convenient than mongoose for example. There is no Python/pyMongo equivalent to JS/mongoose which stands for "this is undefined".

If your goal is to remove the field from the document, you actually have to use `$unset` (see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) or similar kinda manually.

If you want to still have the field but clarify that it's empty/null, you should use `None`.